# Send Emails Via APIs or Code?

Tags: python, web-services, email

I am Using SendGrid to Send Emails to my Users.

There are two ways to send emails via SendGrid.

1 - Via [APIs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html)

2 - Via [Program/Code](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python)

I want to know which one is More Secure and efficient way. I am Using python language, As Python is already slow in processing. So that I want to choose the efficient and fast way.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at [the code of the python library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/blob/master/sendgrid/sendgrid.py), you will notice that it is just a wrapper around the web API. So you are using the web API via python in either case.

Unless you believe that you can write python code which uses the web API much more efficiently than the library does, there is nothing to gain from rolling your own.